# Determining the most common value in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have an array of 10 randomly generated numbers. Then these numbers go into a list. Such as:

```
int[] fams = new int[4];

System.out.println("Number of families with 2 children: " + fams[0]);

System.out.println("Number of families with 3 children: " + fams[1]);

System.out.println("Number of families with 4 children: " + fams[2]);

System.out.println("Number of families with 5 or more children: " + fams[3]);
```

Then I must say:

```
System.out.println("The most common number of children was " + common + ".");
```

I tried the code

```
int common = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < fams.length; i++) {
    if(common < fams[i]) {
            common = fams[i];
```

However, this outputs what the most common fams number is (obviously so). What i need is the most common number of children. For instance, if 2 had 5 families (with an input of 10), I need the number 2 to be the output, not 5. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where's the array of 10 numbers, and where's the list? Your question doesn't sufficiently explain the task.

Comment: Here is your solution friend :) http://ideone.com/CSAx3Y @Eran also has it right

Comment: @user2357112 it says that they are 10 randomly generated numbers, put into a list of either 2, 3, 4, or 5+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep track of both the highest element in `fams` array and the index of that element. The index is what you are looking for.

```
int common = 0;
int commonIndex = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < fams.length; i++) {
    if(common < fams[i]) {
        common = fams[i];
        commonIndex = i;
    }
}
```

At the end of the loop, `commonIndex` would hold what you need.

Comment: I might be misreading the question, but this will return the "maximum" value entered, not the most "common" value entered...

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is a continuation of a previous question he asked. The fams array at index 0 contains the number of families with 2 children, the fams array at index 1 contains the number of families with 3 children, etc.... so he finds the largest number of children between families with 2 children, 3 children etc... This largest number is, in this context, the most common number of children :)

Comment: Ah, I guess context helps them :P

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep the count for each number (for example in a map-reduce scenario with a log of different values) you can sort the collection, and then linearly scan through the list. Every time the value changes, you reset your counter. If your counter reaches max you remeber the number and the index.